# Error executing child request for handler 'Ext.Net.SelfRenderingPage' after response.end

Tags: javascript, c#, view, controller, ext.net

In a Direct method called from a javascript into a cshtml page I have the following last line of code :

```
Response.BinaryWrite(arrayret);
Response.End();
return this.Direct();
```

The method export a gridview in excel. After the method is finished the control pass to the view and I have the error

```
"Error executing child request for handler 'Ext.Net.SelfRenderingPage' after response.end".
```

---

The context is the same I have exposed in my past post.
n my cshtml file i have the following code in script section :

```
     var exportExcel = function() {
          App.PNLCenter.body.mask('Export');
          Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({
          url: "ExportExcel",
          cleanRequest: true,
          isUpload: true,
          params: {
            data: App.gridAllBdg.getRowsValues()
         }
     });
App.PNLCenter.body.unmask();
};
```

in the page code i have a button deslared as shown below :

```
Html.X().Button()
Text("Esporta")
ID("Esporta")
.Handler("exportExcel()")
.Icon(Icon.PageExcel)
.Disabled(false)
.StandOut(false)
```

and in the controller I have the direct method declared as shown below :

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(string data)
{
  //Actions
  Response.Close();
  return this.Direct();
}
```

Wneh the direct method pass the control to the main page I got the error in the line of the cshtml layout invoking the ResourceManager:

```
@Html.X().ResourceManager().StateProvider(StateProvider.Cookie).FormID("idmv")
```

that says

```
Error executing child request for handler 'Ext.Net.SelfRenderingPage'
```

The problem seems related to the Respose.End() that is necessary to close the stream od the exported excel file.

Comment: can u show client side as well,and more code from code behind

Comment: \yes I can. I re-edit the post.

Comment: can u post a simplified test sample to reproduce the exception.